# Jackson deserialize based on property name

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the following two types of JSON objects:

```
{"foo": "String value"}
```

and

```
{"bar": "String value"}
```

Both of them represent a specialized type of the same base object. How can I use Jackson for deserializing them ? The type information is only represented by the keys themselves and not the value for any key (almost all examples use the value of the key for determining the type : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

Answer (score 10):

Jackson doesn't offer an [out of the box solution](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) for that, but it doesn't mean that you are out of luck.

---

Assuming that your classes implement a common interface or extend a common class, as shown below:

```java
public interface Animal {

}
```

```java
public class Dog implements Animal {

   private String bark;
   
   // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Cat implements Animal {

   private String meow;
   
   // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

You can create a custom deserializer based on the property name. It allows you to define a *unique* property that will be used to look up the class to perform the deserialization to:

```java
public class PropertyBasedDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<T> {

    private Map<String, Class<? extends T>> deserializationClasses;

    public PropertyBasedDeserializer(Class<T> baseClass) {
        super(baseClass);
        deserializationClasses = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends T>>();
    }

    public void register(String property, Class<? extends T> deserializationClass) {
        deserializationClasses.put(property, deserializationClass);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
        JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(p);
        
        Class<? extends T> deserializationClass = findDeserializationClass(tree);
        if (deserializationClass == null) {
            throw JsonMappingException.from(ctxt, 
               "No registered unique properties found for polymorphic deserialization");
        }

        return mapper.treeToValue(tree, deserializationClass);
    }
    
    private Class<? extends T> findDeserializationClass(JsonNode tree) {
        
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = tree.fields();
        Class<? extends T> deserializationClass = null;
        
        while (fields.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
            String property = field.getKey();
            if (deserializationClasses.containsKey(property)) {
                deserializationClass = deserializationClasses.get(property);
                break;  
            }
        }
        
        return deserializationClass;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate and configure the deserializer:

```java
PropertyBasedDeserializer<Animal> deserializer = 
        new PropertyBasedDeserializer<>(Animal.class);

deserializer.register("bark", Dog.class); // If "bark" is present, then it's a Dog
deserializer.register("meow", Cat.class); // If "meow" is present, then it's a Cat
```

Add it to a module:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("custom-deserializers", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addDeserializer(Animal.class, deserializer);
```

Register the module and perform the deserialization as usual:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);

String json = "[{\"bark\":\"bowwow\"}, {\"bark\":\"woofWoof\"}, {\"meow\":\"meeeOwww\"}]";
List<Animal> animals = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Animal>>() { });
```

Comment: @Gasol, what is the package for the Entry class used in findDeserializationClass method?

Comment: @ArnavSengupta I believe it is java.util.Map.Entry. 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Answer (score 3):

With `fasterxml jackson`, you can do this:

```
abstract class FooOrBar {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @JsonCreator
        private fun creator(json: Map<String, String>): FooOrBar? {
            return when {
                json.containsKey("foo") -> Foo(json["foo"] as String)
                json.containsKey("bar") -> Foo(json["bar"] as String)
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }
}

class Foo(val foo: String) : FooOrBar() // even can use map delegate if you know what it is
class Bar(val bar: String) : FooOrBar()
```

It is Kotlin, but you will get the idea.

Note the
[`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) is used. the annotated `creator` function has single argument (which is one kind of the two signatures required by `JsonCreator`), JSON is deserialized as a `Map` instance and passed to the `creator`. From here, you can create your class instance.

----------------UPDATE-------------------------

You can also use `JsonNode` for the `creator` function for nested and complex JSON.

```
private fun creator(json: JsonNode): FooOrBar?
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be too late to answer, but still posting my findings.
I encountered exact similar situation, and after going through documentation I came across following [doc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html):

```
// Include logical type name (defined in impl classes) as wrapper; 2 annotations
```

@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({com.myemp.Impl1.class, com.myempl.Impl2.class})

Following is the setup that I used to get it working: (Using same example used by @cassiomolin in above post)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(Dog.class),
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(Cat.class)})
public interface Animal {

}

@JsonTypeName("bark")
public class Dog implements Animal {

   private String bark;
   
   // Default constructor, getters and setters
}

@JsonTypeName("meow")
public class Cat implements Animal {

   private String meow;
   
   // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

You can skip writing custom deserializer unless you have any specific need to handle.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to tell jackson what class you expect:

`Foo readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);`

`Bar readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Bar.class);`

Otherwise it may be worth using XML in this case if you strong types are necessary for your design.

Comment: _"You'll have to tell jackson what class you expect."_ True. But how will you find the right class to be used in runtime? See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463226/1426227).